# Best practice for storing data in a dom element (1 json or multiple data- attributes)

Tags: jquery, json, html

I have a list of 4 articles (with small photo) and a place for 1 article with a bigger photo. When I click an article I will use javascript to display that small article in the big place.

To display the the article with bigger photo there are 3 things I have to know of the article: title, detailUrl and photoUrl (of the bigger photo), I want to catch this with javascript.

Methode 1: using jQuery .find() to search the DOM

```
$("#small").find('img').attr('src');
```

Methode 2: storing everything in seperate data attributes:

```
data-title="titel1" data-detailurl="article1.html"
```

Methode 3: Storing a JSON string

```
data-json="{ "title": "titel1", "detailurl": "article1.html" }"
```

I think the 3th methode is the best (fastest?). Is that right?

Here the html: http://jsfiddle.net/kHbZU/

Comment: Have you considered progressive enhancement? I.e. build up your html and then upgrade it into a dynamic layout.

Comment: It's definitely something we should think about!

Answer (score 3):

Method three is easiest to work with of the ones you listed. Don't worry about the efficiency of string conversion. You'd have to have millions of articles for that to make a real difference. Keep in mind that if you are building this HTML on the server, the JSON will have to be encoded for the HTML to be valid.  You can base-64 encode with `.btoa()/.atob()` to do this easily. If the `.dataset` property is used to set the data on the DOM, the DOM takes care of storing it properly as an object.

A fourth option is to use a `<pre>` block with `display: none;`. This works well if you're building your list on the server. I use this method on the tumblr theme I wrote, http://stiff-theme.tumblr.com/, because I had very little control over the server output. You can leave your JSON unencoded and convert it to to an object easily with `$.parseJSON()`.

HTML:

```html
<pre>
    { "title": "titel1", "detailurl": "article1.html" } 
</pre>
```

Script:

```js
var articles = $.parseJSON( $( 'pre' ).text() );
```

A fifth method is to just use HTML markup and CSS to style. Create your markup of the large version of your article that contains everything. Then use a class to hide, resize, and position for your smaller list display. I like this method best for the problem you're trying to solve.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/ngE8s/

HTML:

```html
<ul id="articles">
    <li>
        <article>
            <img src="large-image-url.png">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <section>
                <p>article body</p>
                ...

            </section>
        </article>
    </li>
    ...

</ul>

<div id="display"><div>
```

CSS:

```css
#articles {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 200px; 
}

#articles li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;  
    height: 32px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

#articles img {
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    width: 30px;    
}

#articles h1 {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0;
}

#display {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 400px;
}

#display img {
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    width: 150px;    
}

#display h1 {
    margin: 0;    
}

p {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Script:

```js
document.getElementById( 'articles' ).addEventListener( 'click', function( event ) {
    var article = event.target.closestByTagName( 'article' );

    if( article ) {
        var display = document.getElementById( 'display' ),
            large = article.cloneNode( true );
        display.removeChild( display.firstChild );
        display.appendChild( large );
    };
}, false );

Element.prototype.closestByTagName = function ( tagName ) {
    return this.tagName && this.tagName.toUpperCase() == tagName.toUpperCase()
        ? this
        : this.parentNode.closestByTagName && this.parentNode.closestByTagName( tagName );
};
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: y u `.html()` on `<pre>` >:( Y U NO `.text()`

Answer (score 2):

What about `jQuery.data` ?

I think it is better then all options.

```
    $.data(document.body, "sortElement", "0"); //set value
    $.data(document.body, "sortElement");        //read value
```

Comment: That would be like methode 2? Using: `$(this).data('detailurl');`

Comment: I what way is it beter then methode 3?

Comment: You can also store entire object in jquery.data() like method 3, ie: $.data({ "title": "titel1", "detailurl": "article1.html" });

Answer (score 2):

Best way would be to use data-xxx attributes. That's what it's meant for.

Just remember you can't use non-utf8 characters in data-xxx attributes.
If it's too much data, or content data, I suggest to store an idreference like

```
<img data-content="#description"/>
```

and have a

```
<p id="#description">some more content with &aacute;ccents</p>
```

Hope it adds to the question.

Greetings,
Bart.

Comment: I agree option-2 is best. Option-3 is a string, which would need to be converted to a javascript object, ex. eval('f='+div1.getAttribute('data-json')). This would eliminate any performance gains, which are negligible at best anyway.